# How to pass array from controller to vue.js v-for?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am trying that from controller pass values (from database column), 
to vue.js component (for select option in v-for), but when I send from controller to blade and get as prop in vue.js and put as data, I get every character in json as one select option.

How I can fix that to work properly and to put json object in v-for select?

**RolesController.php**

```
$roles = Roles::all('name');

        return view('users.create', ['users' => $users]);
```

And in the blade I pass value to vue component:

```
<users-add
roles="{{$roles}}"
></users-add>
```

My **UsersAdd.vue**:

```
<select>
  <option v-for="role in roles" :value="role">
     {{role}}
  </option>
</select>
```

But I **get every character in the list from json** in the select, instead to get every role name in every select row.
For example I get:

```
{
"
n
a
m
e
"
:
"
m
o
d
e
r
a
t
o
r
"
```

Instead

```
moderator
```

Comment: Did you try passing an array? It seems to be parsing an object.

Comment: I was looking again at your code: it's parsing a string. What's the output of `<body>{{ $roles }}</body>`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you have a function in your `RoleController` that looks similar to the following:

```
public function index()
{
    $roles = Role::all('name');

    $users = User:all(); // or however you're obtaining your users

    return view('users.create', compact('roles', 'users'));
}
```

In your `users.create` blade template, you want to have the following:

```php
<users-add :roles="{{ $roles }}"></users-add>
```

Note the colon (:) before the `roles` prop.

Then in your `UserAdd` vue component, something like the following should work for you:

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <label for="role">Role</label>
                <select id="role" name="role">
                  <option v-for="role in this.roles" :value="role">
                     {{ role.name }}
                  </option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: [
            'roles'
        ]
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it works ! I forgot colon (:) in the blade.

Comment: @bakero - Glad I could help.  [: